# Is it possible to drag and drop 3D objects in sap ui5

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

Is it possible to create a 3d object in sap ui5 such that we can move the objects.for example 3D structure of house where i can move the objects like chair.Is there any possible way to achieve this

Comment: There is a library for 3D models but I don't have experience with it: example https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.vk.tutorial.VIT/sample/sap.ui.vk.tutorial.VIT.03 and documentation: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/9be7f960a39748c9b95c3711fb0e52a9

Comment: I've read this.i cannot drag and drop the 3d objects

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to describe exactly what you want to achieve by the information provided in your question. Deciding which development framework to use when you're starting to develop an application is a complicated task.
That said, if you're a going to design a 3D application, like a game for example, there are more appropriated javascript frameworks to handle the task. 
SAP UI5 is meant for enterprise application development, and the main advantage of using it is to have an implementation for the [SAP Fiori](https://www.sap.com/products/fiori/design.html) design principle.

Now back to your question, there's an UI5 control meant to handle 3D visualization:
[sap.ui.vk](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/9be7f960a39748c9b95c3711fb0e52a9)

You can find a tutorial here:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/8deac9d302504962a01149c3cc913ee0

As for the drag and drop, you can check [sap.ui.vk.tools.MoveTool](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.vk.tools.MoveTool). It should be able to let you move objects within the viewport.

You can find an example for that [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.vk.tutorial.VIT/sample/sap.ui.vk.tutorial.VIT.10).